# Creating points in QGIS without having to click through the confirmation dialog on every point?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am creating a fictional map with lots of points to do some proximity analysis.  I would like to drop lots of points at semi-random, by just clicking over and over on the map.  However, with every click, I get a little popup (QGIS 3.6.3, Ubuntu 18.04) that asks me to confirm the autogenerated FID.

How do I do this without being bothered by the confirm box for every single point?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167008/creating-random-points-using-qgis-using-random-points-tool might be helpful and save you some time if you want truly random points... or if you're semi-random fill with random points and delete/move the ones you don't want at their random location.

Comment: This isn't going to work because I'm creating points around roads that will mimic traffic.  So I want to click a lot around some roads and not so much around others.  There is not really a good randomization solution I've found that will do this.

Comment: For a semi-automated solution, you could buffer the road layer, assign a "point count" or "point density" attribute to each buffer, and run `random points inside polygons` using that attribute field to control point count or point density.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the form on "Hide form on add feature" in the Layer properties, see attached image

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the QGIS-fu.